# Using qemu to boot OpenSUSE (or any other OS) with custom kernel

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, qemu, initramfs, initrd

I want to run OpenSUSE as guest with a custom kernel image which is on my host machine. I'm trying:

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -hda opensuse.img -m 512 -kernel \
    ~/kernel/linux-git/arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage -initrd \
    ~/kernel/linux-git/arch/x86_64/boot/initrd.img -boot c
```

But it boots into BusyBox instead. Using `uname -a` shows `Linux (none)`. How do I tell the kernel image to boot with OpenSUSE?

I have OpenSUSE installed into`opensuse.img`, and:

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -hda opensuse.img -m 512 -boot c
```

boots it with the stock kernel.

Comment: If you use absolute paths instead of the `~`'s does that make a difference?

Comment: I don't think so. Still, I tried with absolute paths and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I would try this version of the command line which includes an argument to the booting Kenel telling it where to find the `/dev/sda` that you told `qemu` about:

```
$ cd ~
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -m 512 -s -hda opensuse.img \
     -kernel kernel/linux-git/arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage \
     -initrd kernel/linux-git/arch/x86_64/boot/initrd.img \
     -append "root=/dev/sda"
```

#### References

- [Kernel emulation with Qemu - stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569741/kernel-emulation-with-qemu)

Comment: Or, more precisely, you need to tell the kernel and initrd which is the root file system. If `opensuse.img` is a disk image, the root filesystem is lilely to be a partition, like /dev/sda1. Check the grub.cfg in there to get the correct kernel command line.

Comment: I have tried this, but it still boots up with BusyBox and `uname -a` results in Linux (none) rather than OpenSUSE. Is there a way to edit the grub.cfg file so that it takes in the kernel that is kept on my host machine (i.e. without requiring me to copy the kernel to the virtual machine)?